# Examples of 2d Canvas smoke with mouse interaction.

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm looking for an example of a smoke effect using HTML 2D Canvas where the smoke is effected by the user moving their mouse though the smoke so that the smoke is disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still interesting in this but, here take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyc/Ujz4P/3/)
So, instead of checking if particle touched the edge you should provide mouse x,y coordinates:

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {

        // Set the context variable so it can be re-used
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Create the particles and set their initial positions and velocities
        for(var i=0; i < particleCount; ++i){
            var particle = new Particle(context);

            // Set the position to be inside the canvas bounds
            particle.setPosition(generateRandom(0, canvasWidth), generateRandom(0, canvasHeight));

            // Set the initial velocity to be either random and either negative or positive
            particle.setVelocity(generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity), generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity));
            particles.push(particle);            
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please use a modern browser");
    }
}
```